# Bootstrap reordering columns on different window sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to succeed on reordering columns to look like this:

md++:
[image: medium++]

sm:

[image: small]

xs:

[image: extra small]

What I have at the moment is this:

```
<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-sm-push-8 col-md-push-0' style="background-color:pink;">
  pink
</div>
<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-sm-push-8 col-md-push-6' style="background-color:green;">
  green
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-pull-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
  yellow
</div>
```

My problem is that on "sm" they don't stick together on that right side if one of the blocks has heigth different. See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pYDaGdrsYCHQ9T5OXsRg).

Comment: Plunkr doesn't exist.